# Does Matlab support undo deletion for the codes

Tags: matlab, undo

I'm just going to ask for a really basic question on Matlab which bugs me often when using Matlab.

I sometimes, by accident, delete some chunk of my codes when using Matlab; however, there seems to be no way to undo the deletion or recover those chunks back from my codes.

Is there an undo button or short-cut for deletion of codes?

It's not really a big deal if I cant remember those chunk and write again, but it just seems like a tedious work to do again.

Comment: So... Ctrl-Z? Also, if you're typing in the command line then Matlab keep a history of everything you type and you can (a) drag and drop lines of code and (b) just push the up arrow to get back what you previously typed. If you're working in the editor then I suggest you go with version control software like Git

Comment: @Dan I got this now from the answer, my default undo was 'Control+Shift+Minus' not 'Control+z', so when I did 'Control+Z' it didnt work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The undo button is on the little toolbar in the top-right corner:
[image]

Or you can use Ctrl-Z if you are using the Windows shortcuts.

Comment: Ahh I found this icon now, unfortunately the default for this undo command was 'Control+Shift+Minus'. That's why when i tried to do 'Control+Z' it didnt work

Comment: Oh, I see. Go into Preferences->MATLAB->Keyboard->shortcuts.  If you change the shortcuts from "Emacs Default Set" to "Windows Default Set", then Ctrl-Z will work.  Or you can change the shortcuts individually to whatever you like.

Comment: Nice, I'll try this for sure. To be honest, I was pretty confused on learning these short-cuts since I'm used to Window short-cuts.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a source control system (SCM) like git (git-scm.com) to make backups of your code code.

Note: you need to save in between and then add them to your SCM. Or you could do backups automatically with a cron job.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be an ok idea for back-up. I'll give this a try

Comment: While I agree that revision control is a very good thing, this doesn't really answer the question.